# Trying to separate a string into chunks of 5

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to split my string into chunks of 5 with this:

```
message = [no_space[i + i+5] for i in range(0, len(no_space))]
```

no_space is the same string without spaces

But the code keeps outputting:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The string length is 171

So how do I fix this?

Comment: related: [What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely meant to do this:

```
message = [no_space[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(no_space), 5)]
```

Think about what would happen in your code for a specific `i`, say `90`. `90` is perfectly within the range because the range you specified was from `0` up to (but not including) `len(no_space)`, which is `171`.

If `i == 90`, then `i + i+5 == 90 + 90+5 == 185`. You then request element `185` of `no_space` with `no_space[185]`. Since `no_space` is only `171` characters long, you can't request element `185`, and so you get the `IndexError`.

Hopefully this example will explain how this new code works, with a short string and splitting into 3's:

```
>>> s = 'abcdefghijk'
>>> len(s)
11
>>> list(range(0, len(s), 3))
[0, 3, 6, 9]
>>> s[0:3]
'abc'
>>> s[3:6]
'def'
>>> s[6:9]
'ghi'
>>> s[9:12]
'jk'
>>> [(i, i+3) for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]
[(0, 3), (3, 6), (6, 9), (9, 12)]
>>> [s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jk']
```

Comment: Thansk your  first block of code worked but what exactly does it mean?

Comment: Thanks!! This code worked really well. However in don't quite get what it means so please could elaborate on this matter

Comment: @ZacCotterell On mobile, but see list comprehension

Comment: Thanks but for some reason I'm still not getting it so could you maybe propose another way of doing the putting the message into groups of 5

Comment: Thanks but for some reason I'm still not getting it so could you maybe propose another way of doing the putting the message into groups of 5

Comment: @ZacCotterell This would be the most Pythonic way to do it that I know. Explain what you're not getting and show effort instead of repeating the same comment. Do you know how [list comprehensions](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) work? The interpreter code is intended to explain through code rather than words. Do you understand all of the interpreter code sample?

Comment: Yeah I did but for some odd reason I'm still not getting it?? Don't get me wrong i'm big into coding and get most things but this??

Answer (score 1):

[Funcy](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/stable/overview.html) (a library offering various useful utilities, supporting both Python 2 and 3) offers a [`chunks` function](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/stable/seqs.html#chunks) that does exactly this:

```
>>> import funcy
>>> data = b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> list(funcy.chunks(6, data))
[b'abcdef', b'ghijkl', b'mnopqr', b'stuvwx', b'yz']   # Python 3
['abcdef', 'ghijkl', 'mnopqr', 'stuvwx', 'yz']        # Python 2.7
```

Alternatively, you could include a simple implementation of this in your program (compatible with both Python 2.7 and 3):

```
def chunked(size, source):
    for i in range(0, len(source), size):
        yield source[i:i+size]
```

It behaves the same (at least for your data; Funcy's `chunks` also works with iterators, this doesn't):

```
>>> list(chunked(6, data))
[b'abcdef', b'ghijkl', b'mnopqr', b'stuvwx', b'yz']   # Python 3
['abcdef', 'ghijkl', 'mnopqr', 'stuvwx', 'yz']        # Python 2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
message = [no_space[i + i+5] for i in range(0, len(no_space))]
```

tries to get values for i within 5 of the final index. Thus when you try to use an i of 168 for example, you are going beyond the allowed index for i+5

I just noticed also the typo of using the + in the index of no_space. I think that you meant to get a slice. for example, when i is 10, you actually get the single element at index 25. when i is 83 you get an index of 171 which is an invalid index.

If you grab a slice of 5, you need to skip to the next available index (add 5 at a time) and fix the slice typo.

```
message = [no_space[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(no_space), 5)]
```